# Add height in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the height of a specific `div` that has the class `.fullscreen` 100%.
So I am using the script below - which works brilliantly!

```
// Fullscreen    
$(document).ready(sizeContent);   
$(window).resize(sizeContent);    
function sizeContent() {    
    var newHeight = $("html").height() - $("#header").height() + "px";
    $(".fullscreen").css("height", newHeight);    
}
```

However, if you can take a look here: http://loaistudio.com/sub/test - try to resize the screen size, can you see the div disappearing when the screen size is below 1024? that is because the `#header` is `displayed as none;` when the screen size is below 2014px...

I believe what is going on is something to do with the bit that says "`$("#header").height()`" so the function is relying on the #header as well to work, but since the header is not displayed then it does not work... How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Arr you just trying random code in hope it does what you want ?

Comment: You can pass the height inside `.height()`

Comment: $("#header").height('80px') or simply $("#header").height(80)

Comment: Please review the edit to my question! Thanks.

Comment: An element that isn't displayed has no height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code can make you out the problem with hidden header.

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
    header one
   </header>
<header id="headerTwo">
    header Two
</header>

<section id="wrapper">container</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {height:100px; background-color:grey;}
#headerTwo {height:50px; display:none;  background-color:yellow;}
    #wrapper{ background-color:orange}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #header {display:none;}
    #headerTwo {display:block;}

}
```

**jQuery to change the height**

```
function setLayout(){
    var headerH;
    if( $('#header').is(':visible')){
        headerH = $('#header').height()
    } else if( $('#headerTwo').is(':visible')){
        headerH = $('#headerTwo').height()
    };

    $('#wrapper').css({
        height : $(window).height() - headerH
    })
};

$(window).on('resize', function(){ setLayout(); });
```

in your code try `$(window).height()` instead of `$('html').height();`

Working Example: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pyBX3/)

Comment: Can I simply change from #Header to #headerTwo without using the visible?

Comment: Yes...but then height of wrapper will be fixed according the first header. It will not change according the small one and big one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).css({height: '80px'})
```

else

```
$(selector).css('height', '80px');
```

Comment: sorry, my bad. Updated.

Comment: also fix the first one to `({a:b})`

Comment: curly braces I think can stay as he might want to add multiple properties.

Comment: Yes. I was talking about the `{height, '80px'}` thing